# How do I create a horizontal tech tree for the web?

Tags: javascript, tree, jquery

I'm currently using bootstrap, jQuery and KnockoutJS to create a simple game. I would like to make a horizontal tech/research tree where the player can do research to get bonuses.

I found a CSS version, but there is no way to implement research having two dependencies, so it would limit the possibilities. I also found two commercial JavaScropt libraries, but I'd prefer not to spend $2000.

How do I create a horizontal tech tree for the web?

Comment: "How to create large feature X" is a bit broad. Maybe you can narrow the scope by telling us what you've tried, what's not working, etc? What are all the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

[Techtreejs](https://github.com/7yl4r/techtreejs) might be what you are looking for. [Here is a demo](http://7yl4r.github.io/techtreejs/).

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to run on my computer, but I'll definitely take a look. Thanks! (I will mark as accepted after I tested it, maybe someone else will have other recommendation.